# How can I remove this sidebar from my Search Results page?

Tags: plugins, php, metabox, search, sidebar

I don't want to display this particular sidebar on my website's search results page because it displays details (SITE ADMIN, Wordpress.org, etc) which I want to hide from the user.

How can I hide or remove it. Open to all suggestions. I would be very appreciative of your help.

[image: I want to remove the sidebar on the left]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to your admin panel and then to Appearance -> Widgets, you can remove widgets from the sidebar. You can remove only the Meta widget or all of them if you want. But it will affect all pages probably (unless your theme has different sidebar areas for different page types).

But what is your goal exactly? What do you want to not be seen and by who and why?

Comment: Thank you. I tried exactly what you said and fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this would be to simply remove the sidebar from this specific template in your theme. Of course any modification made to your theme needs to be done in a child theme so it doesn't get nuked the next time you update the original theme. Here's how:

- 1) Create a child theme if you haven't already. You can look up how it's done all over the internet or [in the WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) if you don't know how.
- 2) Activate your child theme in the WP Dashboard.
- 3) Locate your theme's search template. This will most likely (read: not necessarily) be a file called `search.php` that resides in the root folder of the theme.
- 4) Copy it over to your child theme.
- 5) Look for a line that contains the call to the `get_sidebar()` function.
- 6) **Nuke it from orbit**

You should now have the exact same search page, only without a sidebar.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks a lot. I removing all the widgets from my sidebar since I don't need it, and it worked. :-)